# How to Locate a Character Between Alpha and Numeric Characters Using RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I'm working in Access VBA and trying to replace any dashes that appear between an alpha and a numeric character (or vice versa). I am trying to accomplish this using a regular expression to locate a dash (and only the dash) if it appears between a letter and a number or a number and a letter.

I was able to figure out the syntax to identify the pattern I was looking for - however, the expression selects the characters before and after the dash as well - and I am trying to match only the dash.

`/([0-9]-[A-Za-z])|([A-Z-a-z]-[0-9])/g`

```
Actual Results:
1234-56789         nothing is matched
12-A458-125        2-A is matched
1-A-2-B-C985-ABC   1-A, A-2, 2-B,5-A are matched
```

I'm looking to identify only the - character in those situations

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably, `(?<=\d)-(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])-(?=\d)`.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. However, I should add that I am trying to use this in Access VBA. It does not like the positive look ahead or look behind features. I will tinker around with this as a starting point...  but if you have any other thoughts, they would be appreciated! thank you!

Comment: I will have other thoughts if you explain what you are doing: replacing, removing, extracting?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect this - but I am trying to remove any dashes that appear between alpha and numeric characters (or vice versa). For example, I would like to make 12-A-B-92CD4-5 should become 12A-B92CD4-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a pattern to identify hyphens between letters and digits that is valid for regex engines supporting both lookbehinds and lookaheads is

```
(?<=\d)-(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])-(?=\d)
```

The `(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with a digit, `(?<=[A-Za-z])` is the lookbehind that matches the location preceded with a letter, the `(?=[A-Za-z])` positive lookahead requires a letter to appear imediately after the current position and the `(?=\d)` requires a digit.

To remove all the hyphens between letters and digits in VBA code use

```
(\d)-(?=[A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z])-(?=\d)
```

Replace with `$1$2` as the replacement string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bHYeUc/1)

The positive lookbehinds are replaced with capturing groups, and the `$1` / `$2` placeholders (replacement backreferences) refer to the values stored in the corresponding submatches.

You still need lookaheads to enable overlapping matches, and fortunately VBA regex based on the older ECMA Script version supports lookaheads.

**Sample code**:

```
Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "(\d)-(?=[A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z])-(?=\d)"
text = objRegExp.Replace(text, "$1$2")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and the explanation. This makes a lot more sense now.